# How to print custom message using problematic input string when NumberFormatException

Tags: java, throw, numberformatexception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"

How can I access the input string which is causing NumberFormatException to print a custom error message in this form:

```
try {
    /* some code which includes many Integer.parseInt(some_string); */
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("This is not a number: " + input_string_which_causing_the_error);
}
```

Then I should get:

> This is not a number: a

Comment: Easiest way : declare "a" outside try, and use in catch.

Comment: Since NFE hasn't been changed since `JDK1.0`, and presuming the exception comes via `forInputString(String s)` method, you might just strip `For input string: "` and `"` off the exception message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract it from the exception:

```
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage().replaceFirst(".*For input string: ", "This is not a number"));
}
```

Comment: Should that hard as this? declare parsing value out side the try block not enough?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera OP said "some code which includes **many** Integer.parseInt(some_string);" So, this will work without changing the parsing code he has.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera Yes, it's enough. However, in my case it's easier to strip off the error message.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. You should never parse exception messages as their format may change over time, or across JVMs. Secondly, I've personally run a few cases where the JVM throws NumberFormatException with an empty message (`new BigDecimal(String)` does this).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
    String input="abc"; // declare input such that visible to both try and catch
    try {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(input);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("This is not a number: " + input);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be straight forward:

```
String some_string = "12";//retrieval logic
try {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(some_string);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("This is not a number: " + some_string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try/catch NumberFormatException where this can occur and propagate exception to "main" with a throw that contains custom message.

```
try { 
    combinationLength = Integer.parseInt(strCombinationLength);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    throw new NumberFormatException("The parameter \"combinationLength \" must be a number");
}
```

In the main

```
try {
    //some code
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```